# Sending an email using PHPMailer and GMAIL SMTP

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have read every example out in the web and I still cant seem to connect to the GMAIL SMTP. Here is the code that I am running:

```
include("phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php"); // path to the PHPMailer class
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP

$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "myUsername"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "myPassword"; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$webmaster_email = "webMasterEmail@gmail.com"; //Reply to this email ID
$email="someone@gmail.com"; // Recipients email ID
$name="SomeonesName"; // Recipient's name
$mail->From = $webmaster_email;
$mail->FromName = "Me";
$mail->AddAddress($email,$name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email,"Webmaster");
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
$mail->Subject = "This is the subject";
$mail->Body = "Hi,
This is the HTML BODY "; //HTML Body
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body when user views in plain text format"; //Text Body
if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

I tried setting the port in here and I also have the current set up with the following in the class.smtp.php file:

```
$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = 465;
```

I keep getting the same error and I have made sure that ssl is enabled. The error I get is:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.(10061)
```

Comment: I followed the example in http://deepakssn.blogspot.com/2006/06/gmail-php-send-email-using-php-with.html

Comment: Possible duplicate [Send email using GMail SMTP server from PHP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

Comment: Im using PHPMailer and not the default Mail.php with php.ini config

Comment: Maybe your hosting's firewall is blocking the conection with the SMTP, contact them to check this possibility.

Comment: @MarcioSimao Im working off my localhost so there shouldnt be any problems with firewall rules

Comment: Gmail SMTP requires SSL, check your `php.ini` and un-comment `php_openssl` then restart your webserver

Comment: @Adnan I already had that setting enabled and its still not making a difference

Comment: $host = "tls://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = 587;

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned above I had already enabled ssl by getting rid of the ; on the line with php_openssl.dll and restarting Apache. I did some more reading and I found out that some people also had "[PHP_OPENSSL]" before the enabling command. I added it and restarted Apache and everything is working! Thanks for all the comments

In php.ini:

```
[PHP_OPENSSL]
extension=php_openssl.dll
```