# PHPMailer, php.ini configurations

Tags: php, phpmailer

I was trying to find what i should change on **php.ini** settings to allow PHPMailer to work, Is there any guide that explain what i should change on **php.ini**?, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at  the googler results

Tut at : 
http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html
http://www.smtp2go.com/docs/php_mailer/
http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm [more here!]

Shoot at :  
http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10378410-PHP-mailer 
http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/355029/php-mailer-problem

Talk at :  
http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10378410-PHP-mailer
[Sending an email using PHPMailer and GMAIL SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318578/sending-an-email-using-phpmailer-and-gmail-smtp)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

or you can relay GMAIL if you don't have any email server. http://www.icpep.org/use-gmail-account-to-relay-email-from-php-mail-function/